# Why is my compiler giving the error "not a loop label 'moviesMenu'"

Tags: java

I don't know why but my compiler is giving "not a loop label 'moviesMenu'". I want to continue the menu.

I have made 5 classes

Games
Movies
TvShows
Music
Portal

This is Portal Test File. Have I made a mistake? I can't find it. This is a project for my OOP course and I'm making this as my project.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PortalTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int moviesMenuInput;

    Portal portal = new Portal();
    Movies movies = new Movies();
    Games games = new Games();
    TvShows tvShows = new TvShows();
    Music music = new Music();

    portal.displayData();

    Scanner input1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    int menuInput = input1.nextInt();


    moviesMenu:
    {
            switch (menuInput) {


                case 1:



                    System.out.println("1 - ADD MOVIES");
                    System.out.println("2 - REMOVE MOVIES");
                    System.out.println("3 - SEARCH MOVIES");
                    System.out.println("4 - RETURN TO MENU");

                    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);

                    moviesMenuInput = input2.nextInt();


                    switch (moviesMenuInput) {
                        case 1:
                            System.out.println("Enter Movie Name : ");

                            Scanner input6 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String addMoviesNameInput = input6.nextLine();
                            movies.setMovieName(addMoviesNameInput);


                            System.out.println("Enter Movie Release Date : ");

                            Scanner input7 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String addMoviesReleaseDateInput = input7.nextLine();
                            movies.setMovieReleaseDate(addMoviesReleaseDateInput);

                            System.out.println("Enter Movie Genre : ");

                            Scanner input8 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String addMoviesGenreInput = input8.nextLine();
                            movies.setMovieGenre(addMoviesGenreInput);

                            System.out.println("Enter Movie Download Link : ");

                            Scanner input9 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String addMoviesDownloadLinkInput = input9.nextLine();
                            movies.setDownloadLink(addMoviesDownloadLinkInput);

                            System.out.println("MOVIE ADDED");


                            break;

                        case 2:
                            System.out.println("Enter Name of Movie to Delete : ");

                            Scanner input10 = new Scanner(System.in);
                            String deleteMoviesInput = input10.nextLine();


                            if (movies.getMovieName() == deleteMoviesInput) {
                                movies.setMovieName(null);

                                System.out.println("MOVIE DELETED ! ");


                            }


                            break;
                        case 3:
                            System.out.println("Enter Name of Movie to Search : ");
                            break;

                    }
                    continue moviesMenu;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Labels are used to identify loops, in case of nested loops ([see here for examples](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html)). Yours is just there, before a code block, not an actual loop. It should work if you put an infinite loop after the label (`while (true)`), but you really should have a loop with continue/break condition, and do away with the label.

Comment: Really need to try and format your code a bit better, it makes it very hard to read.

Comment: You should probably make an effort to format/indent your code better. This is atrocious to try and read

Comment: Indent your code properly if you would like people to read it. No one should have to try and read this code as it is.

Comment: Sorry It's my first question I have asked in here. So, had some problems I thought formatting it this way would post it.

Comment: Edited the code. Is it better now?

Comment: Better, yes. Although big indentations and some empty lines, but definitely better. Did you look at the link I provided for the use of labels?

Comment: Thanks @AntonH it works. The label did not have loop so it was not Working.

Comment: @touqeer Glad it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your label `moviesMenu`doesn't have a loop. That's why the error you're getting is not a loop label 'moviesMenu'.

To fix that, add a loop to your label:

```
moviesMenu:
  while (true){
    switch (menuInput) {
      //The rest of your code...
      break;
    }
    break;
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much the loop wasn't there that is why it was not working now I can complete the rest of my code.